# Setting up AWS SNS to send Push notifications to iOS devices

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I would like to run a Simple Notification Service (SNS), a service that allows developers to use the AWS (Amazon Web Services) infrastructure to send Push notifications to devices.
Can you please give me pointers as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved because of follow this url step by step..

http://www.adventuresofanentrepreneur.net/creating-a-mobile-appsgames-company/setting-up-aws-sns-to-send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices